# ucharclasses package does not work with TeX Live 2014's fontspec

Tags: fontspec, ucharclasses

With full TeX Live 2014 `ucharclasses` package no longer works with `fontspec`. It works with BasicTeX 2014 because BasicTeX 2014 uses old version of font spec from 2013.

Here is an example document which works with `fontspec` 2013 but no longer works with `fontspec` from full TeX Live 2014:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\usepackage[Latin, Thai]{ucharclasses}
\setDefaultTransitions{\fontspec{Hoefler Text}}{}
\setTransitionTo{Thai}{\fontspec[Scale=1]{Thonburi}}

\begin{document}

Test  ไทย

\end{document}
```

Anybody knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it's a problem due to the new syntax for `\fontspec`. It's better, anyway, to declare the fonts beforehand:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}
\newfontfamily{\thaifont}{Thonburi}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\usepackage[Latin, Thai]{ucharclasses}
\setTransitionTo{Thai}{\thaifont}
\setTransitionFrom{Thai}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

Test  ไทย Test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, egreg. The example in the ucharclasses package should be modified then otherwise it will not work with this new version of font spec.

Comment: @user56595 See https://github.com/Pomax/ucharclasses/issues/7