# fontspec has no effect on changing English font after using \setTransitionsForLatin

Tags: fontspec, ucharclasses

I want to write a paragraph with two languages, Khmer and English. And I want to change font sometimes. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Khmer]{Khmer OS}
\setsansfont[Script=Khmer]{Khmer OS}
\setmonofont[Script=Khmer]{Khmer OS}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}
\setTransitionsForLatin{\fontspec{Latin Modern Roman}}{}
\begin{document}
    អត្ថបទជាភាសាខ្មែរ English text {\fontspec{Lucida Calligraphy} English text in Lucida Calligraphy}
\end{document}
```

It does not change to **Lucida Calligraphy** as I expected. What is the matter and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have the Khmer OS font family on my system, so this is just a comment, not an answer. Instead of using the low-level command `\fontspec` to execute font changes, have you considered issuing the directive `\newfontfamily{\lm}{Latin Modern Roman}` in the preamble and then typing something like `\title{\lm Hello World}`?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188038/ucharclasses-package-does-not-work-with-tex-live-2014s-fontspec

Comment: @Mico Actually, when I write English, it automatically typeset in **Latin Modern Roman** by the command **\setTransitionsForLatin{\fontspec{Latin Modern Roman}}{}**. But problem is that when I want to change English font to **Lucida Calligraphy**, it does not work! It still be in **Latin Modern Roman**

Comment: @egreg I think the problem is a bit different! All what I want is that set **Khmer OS** as my default Khmer font and **Latin Modern Roman** as my default English font so that I can change from English to Khmer and from Khmer to English without using any command.And I have done with **ucharclasses** package using command **\setTransitionsForLatin...** above.The solution in link you suggested is not applicable.If use **\newfontfamily\englishfont{Latin Modern Roman}**, **\setTransitionTo{Latin}{\englishfont}** and **\setTransitionFrom{Latin}{\normalfont}**,the default Englis font is also changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set the transitions correctly and never use `\fontspec` in the document body.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}

\setmainfont{Khmer MN} % the only one I have supporting Khmer
\newfontfamily{\lmodern}{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily{\lucidacal}{Lucida Calligraphy OT}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\setTransitionTo{Khmer}{\normalfont}
\setTransitionFrom{Khmer}{\lmodern}

\begin{document}
    អត្ថបទជាភាសាខ្មែរ English {\lucidacal English text in Lucida
      Calligraphy} and again Latin Modern

\end{document}
```

[image]

The rendering for Khmer is not good, but I know nothing about the language.

More complex setups are possible; here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setmainfont{Khmer Sangam MN}
\newfontfamily{\khmeraltfam}{Code2000}[Script=Khmer]
\newfontfamily{\lmodernfam}{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily{\lucidacalfam}{Lucida Calligraphy OT}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\newrobustcmd{\lmodern}{\lmodernfam\let\currentenglish\lmodernfam}
\newrobustcmd{\lucidacal}{\lucidacalfam\let\currentenglish \lucidacalfam}
\newrobustcmd{\khmernormal}{\normalfont\let\currentkhmer\normalfont}
\newrobustcmd{\khmeralt}{\khmeraltfam\let\currentkhmer\khmeraltfam}

\lmodern \khmernormal % initialize

\setTransitionTo{Khmer}{\currentkhmer}
\setTransitionFrom{Khmer}{\currentenglish}

\begin{document}
អត្ថបទជាភាសាខ្មែរ English {\lucidacal English text in Lucida
អត្ថបទជាភាសាខ្មែរ
Calligraphy} and again Latin Modern

{\khmeralt អត្ថបទជាភាសាខ្មែរ}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is great!!! For rendering we just tell **fontspec** to follow Khmer script rule. **\setmainfont[Script=Khmer]{Khmer MN}**. Thank @egreg :)

Comment: Oh, I have just tested it last moment. I found it affect to Khmer font changing. If want to use other Khmer font, it has no effect. What I have tested is adding `\newfontfamily{\bokor}[Script=Khmer]{Khmer OS Bokor}`. When I try `\bokor{អត្ថបទជាភាសាខ្មែរ}` or `{\bokor អត្ថបទជាភាសាខ្មែរ}` or `\begin{bokor}អត្ថបទជាភាសាខ្មែរ\end{bokor}`, it typesets in **Khmer OS**, the main font. It does not typeset in **Khmer OS Bokor**. What should I do? [Khmer fonts pack](http://khmer.hawaii.edu/Download/KhmerOSfonts.zip)

Comment: @Say OL, Manual font switching works as expected; automatic font switching works as expected; manual and automatic font switching together also work as expected: when the Khmer run of characters is encountered, the font switches to the automatic one. This happens after the manual font command. Manually set the automatic font (`currentkhmer`) to Bokor. Enclose in braces to keep the effect local.

Answer (score 1):

MWE for Bokor

For completeness, and using different fonts to illustrate:

Manual font switching works as expected; automatic font switching works as expected; manual and automatic font switching together also work as expected: when the Khmer run of characters is encountered, the font switches to the automatic font. This happens after the manual font command is processed. Manually set the automatic font (`currentkhmer`) to Bokor. Enclose in braces to keep the effect local.

[image: set automatic font example]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setmainfont[Script=Khmer]{AKbalthom KhmerHand}
\newfontfamily{\khmeraltfam}{Angkor Sovann Preah Vihear}[Script=Khmer]
\newfontfamily{\lmodernfam}{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily{\lucidacalfam}{Lucida Calligraphy}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\newfontfamily\bokor{Bokor}

\newrobustcmd{\lmodern}{\lmodernfam\let\currentenglish\lmodernfam}
\newrobustcmd{\lucidacal}{\lucidacalfam\let\currentenglish \lucidacalfam}
\newrobustcmd{\khmernormal}{\normalfont\let\currentkhmer\normalfont}
\newrobustcmd{\khmeralt}{\khmeraltfam\let\currentkhmer\khmeraltfam}

\lmodern \khmernormal % initialize

\setTransitionTo{Khmer}{\currentkhmer}
\setTransitionFrom{Khmer}{\currentenglish}

\begin{document}
\large
អត្ថបទជាភាសាខ្មែរ English {\lucidacal English text in Lucida
អត្ថបទជាភាសាខ្មែរ
Calligraphy} and again Latin Modern

khmeralt font (in braces) {\khmeralt អត្ថបទជាភាសាខ្មែរ} -- resets currentkhmer

main text (AKbalthom KhmerHand font)  អត្ថបទជាភាសាខ្មែរ

\textbackslash bokor switch \bokor អត្ថបទជាភាសាខ្មែរ --  no effect

bokor in braces: {\bokor អត្ថបទជាភាសាខ្មែរ} -- no effect

{
\let\currentkhmer\bokor
bokor assigned to currentkhmer អត្ថបទជាភាសាខ្មែរ -- works!
}

main text again   អត្ថបទជាភាសាខ្មែរ

red អត្ថបទជា{\color{red}ភាសា}ខ្មែរ more text

\end{document}
```